# Assigning values to a public property not working if other class properties are set by results from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm ready to chuck my computer across the room. Sorry if this a repeat of another question, but I'm trying to reorder items in an object using a certain property. The class with this new property is getting its values from our database using Entity Framework, like so:

```
var products = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<OrderedProduct>(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.tblProductList").ToList();
```

The query is more complex than that, but that's the general idea. There are no virtual methods in the class like MapDataRow() that need a table column name mapped to a property. The class syntax is very basic, like this:

```
public class Product 
{ 
   public Product() 
   {
      MaxAllowed = 1; 
      Selectable = true;
   }
   //properties...
}
```

All of the properties are public, none are static, and there are no methods. The property I'm trying to order by is:

```
public int DisplayOrder {get; set;}
```

This is NOT set in the database; I'm setting it based on other properties that do come from the database, as you can see below. Once I set the DisplayOrder, I want to reorder internetEquipment:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < internetEquipment.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).CodeDetail == "Modem1")
                internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).DisplayOrder = 1;
            if (internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).CodeDetail == "Modem2")
                internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).DisplayOrder = 2;
            if (internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).CodeDetail == "Modem3")
                internetEquipment.ElementAt(i).DisplayOrder = 3;
        }

var equipmentReordered = internetEquipment.OrderBy(equip => equip.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Instead of getting an List object that's ordered by DisplayOrder, I get a randomly sorted list AND all of the DisplayOrder properties are == 0. 
After that long explanation, here's my question: WHY can't I assign a value to my new property DisplayOrder? Thanks!

Comment: Is internetEquipment a non enumerated linq query (so dereffered execution)? Then its logically, because you iterate it everytime again and again and so you get new objects. It thats the case simply iterate it only once by doing *internetEquipment = internetEquipment.ToList()* and it should work then.

Comment: Is `internetEquipment` an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`?  If so you're not updating in memory items.  Basically you should be able to do `internetEquipment[i]` instead of `internetEquipment.ElementAt(i)` for it to work as you want.  You're probably just missing a `ToList` where ever you assign it.

Comment: @BudBrot and juharr: internetEquipment is an IEnumerable object. My understanding of IEnums is not good. I tried setting DisplayOrder several ways and at one point was using indexing, but it never gave me what I needed. That was several tries ago though.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* this is a good answer; I at least figured out how to set the property the way I needed to set it, though there may be better solutions out there. 
Workaround in the Product class:

```
    public int DisplayOrder
    {
        get
        {
            if (ServiceCategory == "D")
            {
                if (CodeDetail == "Modem1")
                    return 1;
                if (CodeDetail == "Modem2")
                    return 2;
                if (CodeDetail == "Modem3")
                    return 3;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```